# Folder size inside a compressed file

Tags: file-management, disk-space

I use windirstat to see the total size of files contained in each folder, but it doesnt support analysis within compressed files.

I am looking for a program that report space usage inside a rar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) has RAR support and will display compressed file/folder sizes.

Comment: 7zip did the trick, but i dont see folder size using winrar

Comment: So it doesn't, just file sizes. Edited to match information.